# space between the first label and radio buttons for an inline radio button group

Tags: css, html

I need to have space between the first label and the inline radio button group as in the following image:
[image]

Example, space between I'm overweight or obese and Yes, No buttons etc and i need to have a horizontal line at bottom as in image. I tried the following:

```
<form class="j-forms" novalidate>
<div class="unit">
<div class="inline-group">
<label style="margin-right: 20px !important;">I'm overweight or obese
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Yes
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
No
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Don't know
</label>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

But the following css is not providing the space:

```
<label style="margin-right: 20px !important;">I'm overweight or obese
```

I tried right-padding too without any effect. **How can i add space, the horizontal lines at bottom and multiple rows of buttons as in the image**.

Soliciting help from CSS experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style `margin-right: 20px` is working the problem is you are putting the radio buttons inside that label only. So it is taking margin from the right side of the screen. Close the `label` tag before `label` with class radio and for the horizontal line, you can simply use `hr` tag.

```html
<form class="j-forms" novalidate>
<div class="unit">
<div class="inline-group">
<label style="margin-right: 60px !important;">I'm overweight or obese</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Yes
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
No
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Don't know
</label>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="inline-group">
<label style="margin-right: 98px">I smoke cigarettes</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Yes
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
No
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="i-radio">
<i></i>
Don't know
</label>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is working perfectly in code snippet. On my page the label displays above the buttons and there is no break between the button groups. The reason why i put the radio buttons inside the label.

Comment: Can’t say anything without looking into the code :)

Comment: It is the same code as above coming from an ajax response php file. Need to check for conflicts. Any way thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Glad I helped :)